# Stop Hook Is Not Being Called When Play Application Is Shutting Down

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, lifecycle, shutdown-hook

I am developing an application using Play Framework 2.5.5 and I'm having issues with adding a stop hook to my class. I have a class called `Broom` like following to schedule a cleaning job.

```
@ImplementedBy(classOf[Broom])
trait AbstractBroom

@Singleton
class Broom @Inject()(ActorSystem: ActorSystem,
                      ApplicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle,
                      Conf: AbstractConf) extends AbstractBroom with Logging {
  private val enabled: Boolean             = Conf.getBoolean("enabled", defaultValue = true)
  private val initialDelay: FiniteDuration = Conf.getFiniteDuration("initialDelay", FiniteDuration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  private val interval: FiniteDuration     = Conf.getFiniteDuration("interval",     FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.DAYS))

  private val actor: ActorRef = ActorSystem.actorOf(Props(new BroomActor(Conf)), BroomActor.actorName)

  private val cancellable: Option[Cancellable] = {
    if (enabled) {
      val firstRun: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now.plusSeconds(interval.toSeconds).withNano(0)

      Log.warn(s"Starting Broom scheduled to $firstRun...")

      val c: Cancellable = ActorSystem.scheduler.schedule(
        initialDelay,
        interval,
        actor,
        Wipe
      )

      Option(c)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }

  ApplicationLifecycle.addStopHook {
    () =>
      actor ! PoisonPill
      cancellable.foreach {
        c: Cancellable =>
          Log.warn("Shutting down Broom...")
          c.cancel()
      }
      ActorSystem.terminate()
  }
}
```

It just regularly sends `Wipe` message to `BroomActor` so it can perform some cleaning on old data. As I want to stop `Broom` when application is shutting down, I added a dependency to `ApplicationLifecycle` and called `addStopHook` method.

For starting `Broom` when application starts, I have a class named `Modules` in `com.example` package like following

```
class Modules extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[Broom]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

which is referenced in my configuration as following.

```
play.modules.enabled += "com.example.Modules"
```

I see starting message when application starts but I don't see stopping message while shutting down. I noticed that cleaning actually continues in the background even though my application is not running. I guess I might be leaking something.

I had pretty much same configuration in another Play 2.5.4 project of mine here https://github.com/mehmetakiftutuncu/quupNotificationsServer for `Heartbeat` class and it just works. What am I doing wrong for this one here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug with Play 2.5.5, see [this issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6466#issuecomment-241642353). You are probably best sticking with 2.5.4 until 2.5.6 is released.

Comment: Thank you very much. Switching back to 2.5.4 fixed it. I'll just update to 2.5.6 when it is out.